# Postfix outbound mail not leaving the server (bounced)

Tags: centos, postfix

I am setting up outbound e-mail for a new Centos 7 server, it just needs to send from PHP not receive.

I've checked that port 25 is open and also listening on 0.0.0.0, which it is so netstat reports:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:smtp            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

I have also checked port 25 is open for outgoing traffic with:

```
telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
```

But when I try and send an e-mail from PHP or from the command line I get this error:

```
May 18 13:17:02 hostname postfix/error[4467]: 05DCA7FFA: to=<test@destination.com>, relay=none, delay=0.06, delays=0.03/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (destination.com)
```

Now I have also setup a port listener on the destination server and this is not picking up any traffic when I do the test that is bounced. So it appears Postfix is not even attempting to deliver.

I have setup up Postfix a few times before and my config is no different this time, the only thing I haven't done is setup SSL, but that shouldn't cause this issue. My Postfix main.cf changes are:

```
 myhostname = mail.yourdomain.com
    mydomain = yourdomain.com
    myorigin = $mydomain
    home_mailbox = mail/
    mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
    inet_interfaces = all
    inet_protocols = all
    mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
```

And after that has worked I have also change master.cf to include:

```
 submission     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
      -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
      -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
      -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
      -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled postfix, rebooted and reinstalled, everything is working normally now.